# converting several gifs to single eps

Tags: linux, file, ghostscript

Im working on LINUX redhat, not sure what version, but most likely recent as its a university machine.

I have a list of over 300 .gif files i'd like to combine into one .eps file (.pdf is also fine).
I've tried using ghostscript to combine them but i get an error

Error: /undefinedfilename in (sDEVICE=epswrite)

I've checked to make sure i have the devices epswrite, and pdfwrite.
The full command i use is:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -q sDEVICE=epswrite -sOutputFile=nuMaxEstimate.eps *_numaxEstimate.gif
```

or:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q sDEVICE=epswrite -sOutputFile=nuMaxEstimate.eps 9820825_numaxEstimate.gif 9821863_numaxEstimate.gif
```

The Full error i get for both instances is:

```
Error: /undefinedfilename in (sDEVICE=epswrite)
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1147/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:70/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
GPL Ghostscript 8.70: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Can anyone help me combine the .gif files to one file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The sDEVICE should be -sDEVICE for starters :-)

On top of that, GIF files are not PostScript,so you can't just submit them direct to Ghostscript.